# Is there a way to conditionally include or exclude a navigation property when querying Database using EF Core

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, .net-core, ef-core-2.2

I'm attempting to conditionally include or exclude a navigation property when querying Database using `DbSet<T>` as follows:

```
var recordList = await dbContext.DbSet<T>
.Include(i => i.NavigationProp ?? null)
.AsNoTracking()
.ToListAsync();
```

I would like to exclude the Navigation property if it is null but include it when there is a value in the database. Any attempt to achieve this throws exception:

> Message = "The Include property lambda expression 'i => (i.FeedbackImage ?? null)' is invalid. The expression should represent a property access: 't => t.MyProperty'. To target navigations declared on derived types, specify an explicitly typed lambda parameter of the....

Why does this `.Include(i => i.NavigationProp ?? null)` fail when `Include(Expression<Func<T, T>>)` method accepts an Expression?

Comment: How do you know to exclude it when the only way to get to know not to include it is to include it? 

Comment: @JohnyL well that is the mystery this question is trying to demystify, is there a way to conditionally include or exclude navigation properties?

Comment: @JohnyL I'm trying to check if the Navigation property has a value, if true then it must be included else ignored.

Comment: I can't figure out what you mean by "excluding" the navigation property. Do you want to add an `Include` statement conditionally (that is, when class `T` has this property)? Or do you want to exclude it from `T` *instances*? The latter wouldn't be necessary because `Include` would result in 'null` navigation properties when the property is a reference or otherwise empty collections.

Answer (score 1):

It fails because `Include(Expression<Func<T, T>>)` gets actually translated to `Include(string)` internally and eventually `Include(string)` will need a property name and that's what the error is telling you, that's how entity framework is doing it.

**Update:**

Certainly not an elegant solution but you could try something like this:

Adding the navigation property as an interface to your models:

```
public interface IHasNavigationProperty
{
    public NavigationProp NavigationProp { get; set; }
}
```

Models will implement it:

```
public class MyModel : IHasNavigationProperty
{
    public NavigationProp NavigationProp { get; set; }
}
```

And a generic method that will check for that interface and execute the your include if the class implements it:

```
IList<T> GetRecords<T>() where T : class
{
    var hasNavigationPropertyInterface = typeof(IHasNavigationProperty).IsAssignableFrom(typeof(T));
    var query = _context.Set<T>().AsQueryable();
    if (hasNavigationPropertyInterface)
    {
        var navigationPropertyName = nameof(NavigationProp);
        query = query.Include(navigationPropertyName);
    }
    var recordList = query.AsNoTracking()
        .ToList();
    return recordList;
}
```

**Update 2 :**

Thinking about it you can just check for the property name instead of adding an interface:

```
private IList<T> GetRecords<T>() where T : class
{
    var hasProperty = typeof(T).GetProperty(nameof(NavigationProp)) != null;
    var query = _context.Set<T>().AsQueryable();
    if (hasProperty)
    {
        var navigationPropertyName = nameof(NavigationProp);
        query = query.Include(navigationPropertyName);
    }
    var recordList = query.AsNoTracking()
        .ToList();
    return recordList;
}
```

Comment: Good day, thank you for your answer, this filters records based on Where clause, it will not work in my case as the NavigationProp is optional but everything else must be retrieved.

Comment: My bad then, this solution is not for a filter i will edit it.

Comment: Can you like add the filter on exactly the types that has the NavigationProp ? not sure it will work but you could maybe join them with an interface ?

Comment: Not sure I understand your kind suggestion clearly, would you mind posting a sample.

Comment: the problem with the solution is that you are checking the existence of the Navigation property, I'm trying to check if the Navigation property has a value, if true then it must be included else ignored.

Comment: Then David Browne - Microsoft answer is the one you need.

Comment: It answers what I thought was a bug, trying to access a navigation property that may not have a value in the database table. The navigation property is optional, when I include it in my query it throws an exception.

Answer (score 1):

> I'm trying to check if the Navigation property has a value, if true then it must be included else ignored.

So just

```
var recordList = await dbContext.DbSet<T>
.Include(i => i.NavigationProp)
.AsNoTracking()
.ToListAsync();
```

The Navigation Property will be loaded, unless the related Foreign Key value is null, in which case it will be Null.

Comment: Thank you very much for the clarity, I guess the exception I have is coming from some other place.